# using Python Selenium, Can't find an element on Pinterest.com yet I can see it using inspector in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, pinterest

I've written a python script that logs into my Pinterest account and puts a word into the search box element {searchBoxInput} after log in. This worked perfectly in the past. 
Now when I do a search the elements on the webpage by name or id using selenium, I can't see it in the list anymore, yet when I go to Web inspector and look at the code on the page I can see it in the web page code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def search_box():
    """enter into search box and click search"""
    searchWindow = driver.find_element_by_id("searchBoxInput")  # type: WebElement
    searchWindow.send_keys('Sweden')
    searchWindow.click()
    searchWindow.send_keys(u'\ue007') # send 'return key' click
    Get_elements_by_name()
    Get_elements_by_id()

def element_present():
    """find element seachInputBox"""
    try:
        search = driver.find_element_by_name("searchBoxInput") #

        print("found <%s> elements with class name !"  % (search.tag_name))



    except:
        print('Was not able to find an element searchBoxInput.')
```